# Cant use Linq WHERE/IN/JOIN with Entity Framework on many to many

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, entity-framework

I can do this very simply in SQL, but trying to learn how to do this in Linq using Entity Framework.

I have a User, a User can have multiple Groups, and a group can have multiple Permissions.

I would like to get all the permissions for a user.

I have the following DbSets in my DbContext

```
public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
```

And there classes are like so

```
public class User : Entity, IUser<long>
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    public User()
        : base()
    {
        this.Groups = new HashSet<UserGroup>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<UserGroup> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group : AuditableEntity
{
    public Group() {
        this.Permissions = new HashSet<GroupPermission>();            
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GroupPermission> Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class Permission 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Permission()
    {

    }
}
```

To cope with the many to many relationships, i also have these classes

```
public class UserGroup
{

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public long GroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }

}

public class GroupPermission
{
    public long PermissionId { get; set; }
    public long GroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

Now in SQL i would simply do

```
SELECT Permission.* 
FROM Permission
    INNER JOIN PermissionGroup ON Permission.Id = PermissionGroup.PermissionId
    INNER JOIN Group ON PermissionGroup.GroupId = Group.Id
    INNER JOIN UserGroup ON Group.Id = UserGroup.GroupId
WHERE UserGroup.UserId = @UserId
```

Can someone please tell me why i cant do this in LINQ?  Well i know i can, but i cannot figure out how.

**EDIT**

context.PermissionGroup and context.UserGroup are not DbSets in my context.

```
List<Permission> result;
using(DataContext context = new DataContext())
{
   result = (from permission in context.Permissions
             join permissionGroup in context.PermissionGroup on permission.Id equals permissionGroup.Id
             join g in context.Groups on permissionGroup.GroupId equals g.Id
             join userGroup in context.UserGroup on g.Id equals userGroup.GroupId
             where userGroup.UserId == user.Id 
             select permission).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joining in SQL doesn't automatically mean that you should join in LINQ. Use navigation properties whenever possible. Your case becomes much simpler if you do that, and use `SelectMany` for this:

```
from u in db.Users
select new { 
             u.UserName,
             Permissions = u.Groups
                            .Select(ug => ug.Group)
                            .SelectMany(g => g.Permissions)
                            .Select(gp => gp.Permission
           }
```

Comment: Well i did ask above whether i need to add a DbSet to my context for every table join, but was told that i should.  I would happily use your code, as i have the navigation properties (as you can see), but your code doesnt work. Permissions doesnt exist in the code  g => g.Permissions, g would return a UserGroup, which has properties of UserId, User, GroupId, Group

Comment: Ok, this is looking promising, but what if i already had the user as a parameter?  So instead of db.Users, how would i modify your code? Basically i have a function that accepts a User and i want to return there permissions. or is this not possible?

Comment: You can simple add a `where`, `from u in db.Users where u.UserName == user.UserName`, where `user` is the user that enters the function, and assuming UserName is unique. (I don't see a primary key property, but you'd probably want to filter by that one).

Comment: Yeah i thought that in the end. thanks, marked yours as the answer, as you answers what i wanted originally

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
var linqQuery=(from p in Permission
                    join pg in PermissionGroup on p.Id equals pg.Id
                    join g in Group on pg.GroupId equals g.Id
                    join ug in UserGroup on g.Id equals ug.GroupId
                    where ug.UserId == USERID 
                    select p);
```

Comment: Where are you getting PermissionGroup and UserGroup from? If _context is my DbContext, i have no reference to a DbSet called PermissionGroup or UserGroup??

Comment: create a Dbcontext reference say ctx and use it as ctx.Permission , ctx.PermissionGroup, ctx.Group & ctx.UserGroup

Comment: That doesnt even compile.  Says no reference to ctx.Permission etc, added to my original post

Comment: finished edit.. Please check my original class definitions and my DbContext.  I have said which DbSets i have.  The userGroup  is referenced by the User class, called Groups. And GroupPermission by the Group class called Permissions

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own `DbContext` class where all your database tables are represented as `DbSets`

```
public partial class OwnContext: DbContext
{
   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
   public DbSet<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; }
   public DbSet<PermissionGroup> PermissionGroups { get; set; }
}
```

you have to create an instance of that class with a *using statement* and execute your query in the *using statement*.

```
List<Permission> result;
using(OwnContext context = new OwnContext())
{
   result = (from permission in context.Permissions
             join permissionGroup in context.PermissionGroups on permission.Id equals permissionGroup.Id
             join group in context.Groups on permissionGroup.GroupId equals group.Id
             join userGroup in context.UserGroups on group.Id equals userGroup.GroupId
             where userGroup.UserId == user.Id 
             select permission).ToList();
}
```

Comment: No, this doesnt work. 
from p in Permission has error "Could not find implementation of the query pattern for source type "my.name.space.Permission" 'Join' not found.
join pg in PermissionGroup has error "The name 'PermissionGroup' does not exist in the current context"
join g in Group AND join ug in UserGroup have error "my.name.space.Group/UserGroup is a type that is being used as a variable"
Copied my exact code to question post.

Comment: @user2736022 Do you have  a reference to 'System.Linq'?

Comment: You edited your answer lol.  Still not working, but closer. Yes i have System.Linq referenced. But context.PermissionGroup and context.UserGroup are not DbSets in my context.  I have updated my code again, as you have put context.Permission instead of context.Permissions, see my code

Comment: @user2736022 Ooh, now I see it. :) Can you add PermissionGroup and UserGroup to your DbContext?

Comment: Should i have too?  Surely you do not need to add each relationship join as a dbSet in DbContext. I dont mind if i have to do this over a couple linq queries instead of just 1

Comment: Ok, i think i have misunderstood something then. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
using (var context = new NombreDeEntityDataModel)
{
    var query = from a in context.Permission
                join b in context.PermissionGroup on a.id equals b.PermissionId
                join c in context.Group on b.GroupId equals c.id
                join d in context.UserGroup on c.id equals d.GroupId
                where d.UserId = @UserId
                select a;
}
```

Comment: I do not have context.PermissionGroup, nor context.UserGroup as a DbSet in my context.  Only as a navigation property on objects